# Registration - Accept only work emails

Tags: php

I'm working on a PHP application.
I do not want people with free emails (like gmail, ymail etc.) to sign up for it.

How can i restrict the registration to work emails only??

Thanks,
Sash

Comment: I know at least one person whose work email is a gmail address.

Comment: Put it this way; if you _insisted_ upon having my work email for sign-up, I'd be out of there PDQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can blacklist some domains, but people can just make up nonsense and how can you verify that it's a work e-mail? I think this is a really artificial and odd restriction.

Not everyone has "work email" anyway.

As for the blacklist, if you split the e-mail by @, you can compare the second part against an array of disallowed domains.

Comment: pls check here: https://ovs.acunetix.com/#/register/, they accept only work emails, i want to do something like that

Comment: it's some random scam form, I'm not gonna fill that in.

Comment: Lol! It isn't. You heard of acunetix?